# Storing array data while using foreach

Tags: php

I have the following data here.

```
[places] => Array
            (
                [0] => Drama
                [1] => School
                [2] => Shounen Ai
                [3] => Slice of Life
            )
```

I am trying to store this data into **WordPress** tags, however it's returning only singular letters.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($t['places'] as  $tag=>$value){
    $numbers = $i++;
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id , $t['places'][$numbers], "drama_tag",true);
}
```

This is what it returns, what am I doing wrong?

[please edit the image into the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxn0X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping over the array in your `foreach`; you don't need to set up your own increment.

Instead of `$t['places'][$numbers]`, you're simply looking for `$value`:

```
foreach($t['places'] as $tag=>$value) {
    wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $value, "drama_tag", true);
}
```